# Discord.py: Interact with other bots

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there any way to interact with other discord bots Which have a bot filter?  I want to make a discord dankmemerfarmer bot. Tried nothing, sorry.
I think many people did it using requests but i didnt understand those.
Also any way to send messages without being marked as bot? I know thats bad, but i can risk getting banned in order to get a few coins. Also thats a lil thing and i guess many people did it so it aint that bad.

Comment: If Dank Memer doesn't respond to commands from other bots, I don't see a way to do it.

Comment: I think you’re talking about a self-bot, they are however strictly against the discord ToS so I doubt you’ll get any help here

Comment: You only can use self bots for this propose.

Comment: I did it.
But when i use
discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix=';',self_bot=True)
Is self_bot kwarg necessary?  I saw it worked if it was false too and it just went slower

Comment: I did it. You just have to devTools and network and find a json (forgot name) and use that token, and bot=false in client.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.
But when i use

```
discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix=';',self_bot=True)
```

Is self_bot kwarg necessary?  I saw it worked if it was false too.

Well i just had to go in Discord > DevTools > Application > Click Mobile-Device icon > Search 'token' in filter search box > Copy token value.
And use that token instead of bot token. And use

```
bot.run('token',bot=False)
```

Lol i wonder why discord still has its support even if it is banned.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible due to dank memer only responding to users. Although against discord Terms of Service, discord.py **does** support userbots in 1.7.3. But don't use it.

Comment: I did it.
But when i use
discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix=';',self_bot=True)
Is self_bot kwarg necessary?  I saw it worked if it was false too and it just went slower